# How to prevent back button after logout in ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 app

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I am working on ASP.NET Core MVC web application. I have created a controller for logout and it's working fine. I am trying to remove cache when user clicked on logout. I used the below given code but it is not working in case of cache removal. Here is my logout controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public ActionResult Logout()
{
  HttpContext.Session.Clear();
  return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
}
```

I even tried to use code given below to remove cache but it is not working too.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

// Clears the session at the end of request
Session.Abandon();
```

How can I remove cache or prevent back button click when user logged out in Asp .Net Core app.

Comment: Session.Clear() simply clears the session variables, it doesn't log anyone out. The user remains logged in

Comment: Check the [Introduction to Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) docs. The logout page is already available. You can customise it if you want. That's shown in the [Logout section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#log-out-1). The actual logout operation is performed by calling SigningManager.SignoutAsync

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How can I use SignOutAsync() in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[HttpPost]            
[Route("logout")]         
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
  await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
  return new JsonResult(new
  {
    //return whatever you want
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Javascript. When you clicked on logout I assume you are showing an HTML page that says "You are successfully logged out" or some kind of it.

In that page add this script

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >  
    function preventBack() { window.history.forward(); }  
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);  
    window.onunload = function () { null };  
</script>
```

This will prevent the user from clicking on back button of the browser

Comment: But when I right click on back button in chrome, I can go back